# Shiny Dashboard menu Item

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The menu items in the shiny dashboard have a tiny white dot next to each line item. Can we disable/remove these white dots. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Below is a sample code to test.

ui.R

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title="Dashboard")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  menuItem("Menu1",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub1", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub2", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub3", icon = icon("dashboard"))
           ),
  menuItem("Menu2",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub12", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub22", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub32", icon = icon("dashboard"))))
body <- dashboardBody()
dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {}
```

EDIT:
Screenshot for the clarification comment to @Batanichek

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `sidebarMenu`

Try

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Menu1",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub1", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub2", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub3", icon = icon("dashboard"))
  ),
  menuItem("Menu2",icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("Sub12", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub22", icon = icon("dashboard")),
           menuSubItem("Sub32", icon = icon("dashboard")))))
```

To move submenu try to edit css like

```
body <- dashboardBody(tags$style(HTML(".sidebar-menu .treeview-menu{     padding: 0 0 0 50px;}")))
```

Comment: Can we move the "submenuitems" towards right, just to make it more clear to distinguish menu and sub menu items. In the above example, "Menu1" and "Sub1" are almost same in the vertical line.